# Is It possible to control a real telegram account by php and telegram api

Tags: php, webhooks, telegram, php-telegram-bot

I want to Control a Telegram Account With php !
is it possible to connect to telegram  like that ?
because i saw a robot like this in one of my groups ! that used a mobile number not botfather key !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is Possible. You need to build a Telegram Client in code. there are libraries in several languages for this.

But you can also write such code yourself.

Comment: thanks charles , i know php but i heared lua is best language for this job ? is this true ? where is api about building telegram client ? i just found telegram robors documents !  is this a goof sample for my start ? https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client ! why lua is better than php in telegram client ?!

Comment: @Parsi What language are you comfortable with? That should determine what works best for you. Also if you have the time and what to learn, you could build a Telegram client from scratch for yourself.

Comment: i am comfortable with php if it can handle this kind of stuff , the job of robot is joining groups and send advertising messages , also analysis all messages for special words and find group join links ! and save users ids to database so i think we have a very big data to handle and so many requests , script is running on a server (no vps or host ...)
and i already got the project so have no time for learning !

Comment: @Parsi some advice to you, Ensure you are only sending advertising messages to users who have opted-in to receive your messages

Comment: @charls Thank Your , but i am not the owner of company ! I am Just a Employee I pass your advice to them

Comment: upvote.. seems you have lots of experiences about telegram API. I'm trying to make something like what OP mentioned in the question. May you please give me some clues? I use PHP language.

Comment: @martinaj what do you want to achieve? You can actually use any language you are comfortable with.

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu I want to achieve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748981/can-i-access-my-telegrams-messages-as-json). Do you have any solution? All I know is doing that is possible. But is there any implemented example in PHP?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu Do you have an example for that?

Comment: @HAßdøµ try to use the tdlib here: https://core.telegram.org/api#tdlib-build-your-own-telegram and here: https://github.com/tdlib/td